# (C++) Calculating [(1! / 1^1) + (2! / 2^2) + ... + (20! / 20^20)] with using subfunctions of factorial and power

Tags: c++, function, factorial, exponentiation

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int power(int a, int b); // Subfunction to calculate a^b
int fact(int c); // Subfunction to calculate factorial

int main() {
    
    int x=0;
    
    for(int i=1 ; i<=20 ; i++)
    
    x+= fact(i) / power (i,i);  // needs to calculate like [(1! / 1^1) + (2! / 2^2) + (3! / 3^3) + ...... + (20! / 20^20) // assigned x and sum it with counter to calculate final result
    
    cout<<x;
    return 0;
}


int power(int a, int b) { // a^b subfunction
    
    unsigned long long int multip=1; // written the biggest type just in case (idk if i need it)
    
    for (int i=1; i<=b; i++) {
        
        multip*=a;
        
    }
    
    return multip;
}

int fact(int c) { // factorial subfunction
    
    unsigned long long int multip=1;
    
    for (int i=c ; i>=1 ; i--) {
        
        multip*=i;
        
    }
    
    return multip;
}
```

I tried to calculate **[(1! / 1^1) + (2! / 2^2) + ... + (20! / 20^20)]** but somewhy program didn't work at all. [output](https://prnt.sc/t_lz60svEIrq)

I'm sorry if the mistake is obvious I've been trying for long hours and can't think much right now. I will return to the replies with fresh head.Have a good day.

Comment: The factorial often appears in fractions where most of it cancles out. Same here: `20* 20* 20...*20 / 20* 19 * 18 *... == 1 * 20/19 * 20/18 * ...`. The factorial overflows easily, `20/19` and the other terms and the product does not overflow.

Comment: Your `multip` variable is `long long` but the function returns a simple `int`?

Comment: when you are dealing with factorial, just assume that any arithmetic type is going to fail, and you need a big_integer class

Comment: Base on title you are calculating sum of some series. Problem is you've written a code which is not useful if calculating this sum is written properly. This code is useful in flowed implementations (it has integer overflow). I recommend you to create new question with full task description where you include entire code you've wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some serious problems with your types:

```
int power(...);
int fact(...);
```

=> this should be `long long`.

In top of this, you are doing integer division, while you need floating point division:

```
fact(i) / power (i,i);
```

... should be:

```
((double) fact(i)) / power (i,i);
```

Comment: Using `std::static_cast<double>(fact(i))` rather than C-style cast would be more explicit